# How to automatically accept privacy agreement when installing VS2017 via the command line?

Tags: windows, powershell, automation, visual-studio

As part of managing environments, I want to install Visual Studio 2017 via the command line.  However, I'm running into issues installing 2017 that wasn't encountered setting up 2015.  Following the [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/use-command-line-parameters-to-install-visual-studio) I've got a simple Powershell script:

`Start-Process C:\\windows\\temp\\vs2017\\vs_professional_2017 --ArgumentList "/Quiet /NoRestart /Log C:\\Windows\\Temp\\InstallVs2017\\install.log" -Wait`

Which worked just fine for VS2015.  And it does start the installation, but after a couple of seconds displays the dialog box for accepting the privacy statement and license terms.  I can't seem to find a `--accepteula` flag or something similar to get past it (on a side note, I would have thought that given `quiet` is supposed to suppress the UI that it would suppress this as well).  There is a comment on this issues in the [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/use-command-line-parameters-to-install-visual-studio), but they couldn't figure out a way past it.  How do you automatically accept it?  I feel like I'm missing something obvious, but I have yet to figure it out.

Comment: have you tried below options in the answers ?

Comment: @Aravinda I did try them but with no luck.  Turns out `quiet` does work, but I wasn't setting the options right.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did actually manage to get this to work.  The first problem is that options can no longer be denoted with `/`, they have to be denoted with `--`.  Apparently `/` is disallowed now, I had missed that somewhere.

I also dropped the `/Log` option.  It doesn't exist as a option for VS2017, although if you still need to get the installation logs they do have a [way to get them](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/troubleshooting-installation-issues#how-to-get-the-visual-studio-installation-logs).

After making those changes, VS2017 installed successfully without me having to manually accept the terms; it wasn't picking up the options because I wasn't using `--`.  I also added `.exe` for completionist's sake to the executable.

`Start-Process C:\\windows\\temp\\vs2017\\vs_professional_2017.exe --ArgumentList "--quiet --norestart" -Wait`

Answer (score 3):

Try these switches, individually and combination, or else open the MSI with Orca and change the EULA variable.

```
ACCEPT=YES
ACCEPTEULA=1
ASSOCIATE=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Powerbi msi accepts `"ACCEPT_EULA=1"` . You can give it a try if everything fails for Visual Studio 2017.